# What is the word to describe a small saying that doesn't say anything too useful?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking of the word platitude, and I thought of aristoteles because of the "plato"-like sounding thing even though apparently it comes from French. Thanks...

Comment: Are you thinking of a [platitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platitude)?

Comment: Yes that was the exact word I was thinking about

Comment: Converted to answer.

Comment: I just saw that you changed your question.  It should be closed and deleted in its current form.  If you roll back the edit, it might stay.

Comment: No, you should not change your question this way after anybody asked to its original form. I endorse cornbread's call to close.

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of a *[platitude](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/platitude)*?

> An often-quoted saying that is supposed to be meaningful but has become unoriginal or hackneyed through overuse; a cliché.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platitude):

> A platitude is a trite, meaningless, biased, or prosaic statement, often presented as if it were significant and original. The word derives from plat, the French word for "flat."

Examples:

- "The power of friendship"
- "Go with the flow"
- "Everything happens for a reason"
- "It is what it is!"
- "If it's meant to be, it's meant to be"
- "We need to do what we can do"